# C# Asp.net Css class in code behind does not work when app is published

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, bootstrap-4, webforms

I'm quite new to the ASP.net Framework Webapps enviroment, and came accross an issue.

If I set a Css class based on a condition in the C# code behind it works perfectly fine. The moment I publish the app to IIS is does not work any more. For sanity I've also tried publishing the app as Debug or Release mode, which made no difference.

The data is loaded on the page_load event of the page, and the updatepanel is refreshed here.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ID="upcontent">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="jumbotron" style="padding: 5px; background-color: lightgrey; overflow: hidden">
                <div class="card bg-secondary mb-3" style="max-width: 35rem; min-width: 35rem; float: left; overflow: hidden;">
                    <div class="card-header">Work Order Details</div>
                    <div class="card-body">

                        <asp:GridView ID="GVMain" margin-top="10px" runat="server" EmptyDataText="Record is empty" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="true" ShowHeader="false" DataKeyNames="PropertyName" class="table table-hover" OnPageIndexChanging="GVMain_PageIndexChanging" OnRowDataBound="GVMain_RowDataBound" BorderStyle="NotSet" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10">
                            <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" />
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </div>
                </div>
     </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

Code Behind:

```
        protected void GVMain_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                // Check the XXXX column - if empty, the YYYY needs highlighting!
                if (e.Row.Cells[1].Text == "Mon, 01/01/0001")
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[1].CssClass = "text-warning"; // ...so highlight it
                }          
            }
            upcontent.Update();
        }
```

Please assist, see attached images below between dev and deployed enviroment

[Working from Dev Enviroment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebWKq.png)

[Working from Inspect Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJRxx.png)

[Not Working when Depoyed on IIS Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wm40k.png)

[Not Working when Depoyed on IIS Server Inspect Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFnX9.png)

Would it be possible to assist. One thing to note is this is from the same browser on the same PC.

Comment: It seems to be a regional issue. On your production server the date format uses '-' instead of '/'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example you give it is not clear what the actual data (type) is. But ideally you would not want to compare with a text representation of a date, because it is subject to regional setting of the machine it is running on. Better would be to compare with an actual datetime. So assuming the data you're binding to is of type `SomeObject` which has a property DateTime 'TheDate' then you could have the following code in the `OnRowBinding` event:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    var value = e.Row.DataItem as SomeObject;
    if (value != null && value.TheDate == DateTime.MinValue)
    {
        // do whatever is appropriate
```

Comment: Thank you, casting the value as someObject seemed to solve the issue

Comment: Glad to be of help :) Mind marking the question as answered?